# How to prove the inequality involving a sum of a sequence divided by $\sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove # 19 on page 41 of Bartle and Sherbert's Real Anaylsis.  Here is the problem:

$\forall k$ let $c_k>0$, show:

$$
\frac{c_1+c_2+...+c_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq (c_1^2+c_2^2+...+c_n^2)^\frac{1}{2}
$$

I'm having trouble showing this with induction, and I am hopeful that someone might give a hint to point me in a good direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Try squaring both sides and consider the equivalent inequality: $(c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n)^2 \le n (c_1^2 + c_2^2 + \cdots c_n^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change this problem to be: $$(c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n)^2 \le n (c_1^2 + c_2^2 + \cdots + c_n^2)$$

Then we can establish a quick lemma: $$x^2 + y^2 \ge xy + yx.$$

This is established by noticing: $(x-y)^2 \ge 0$ and so $x^2 + y^2 \ge 2xy = xy + yx$.

Now if we consider the case when $n=2$ we see that
$$(c_1 + c_2)^2 = c_1^2 + c_1 c_2 + c_2 c_1 + c_2^2 \le c_1^2 + c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_2^2 = 2(c_1^2 + c_2^2).$$

The same reasoning can be carried out for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: This is a method that avoids using convexity and is a bit more elementary.

Comment: I appreciate this.  It makes a little more sense how to start on induction now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the convexity of $x\to x^2$.

details:

$$\left(
\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}n
\right)^2 \le
\frac{x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2}n\\
\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}n
 \le
\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2}}{\sqrt{n}}\\
\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}{\sqrt{n}}
 \le
{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2}}
$$

---

alternatively, you can use concavity of $x\to x^{1/p}$,  with $p\ge 1$ ; in you example $p=2$:
$$
\sqrt[p]{\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}{n}}
\ge \frac{\sqrt[p]{x_1}+\cdots +\sqrt[p]{x_n}}{n}
$$

Take $x = c_i^p$.

$$
\sqrt[p]{\frac{c_1^p+\cdots +c_n^p}{n}}
\ge \frac{c_1+\cdots +c_n}{n}\\
\sqrt[p]{{c_1^p+\cdots +c_n^p}}
\ge \frac{c_1+\cdots +c_n}{n^{1-1/p}}
$$

Comment: Thank you- this makes perfect sense and is a great quick answer, but left me wondering if there was a way to not use concavity (this section was in the properties of R and convex functions are much later).

I finally found that using the Cauchy-Schwarz (mentioned in this section) and letting the first sequence equal $c_k$ and letting the second sequence equal all 1, the inequality pretty much falls out.

Comment: of course. but if you replace $2$ with $p$ it becomes much harder, when it remains the same with the use of convexity.